# function need to run code within sequentially Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Hello I have here a function. Inside the function, im running a loop. after the loop runs I have an IF statement. The issue here is javascript is asynchronous as we all know. Is it possible to have this non-asynchronous ? Wherein the loop finishes then proceeds to the IF statement. Below is my function:

```
    async function analyzeVins() {
       const vinsToAnalyze = vins.split('\n');

    if (vinsToAnalyze.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    for (let x = 0; x < vinsToAnalyze.length; x++) {
      if (vinsToAnalyze[x].length > 10) {
        setErrorVinsArr([...errorVinsArr, vinsToAnalyze[x]]);
      } else {
        setValidatedVins([...validatedVins, vinsToAnalyze[x]]);
      }
    }
    if (missingVinsArr.length <= validatedVins.length) {
         console.log('valid');
       } else {
         console.log('invalid');
       }
   }
```

Comment: If i were you, I'd try to extract `setErrorVinsArr` and `setValidatedVins` outside of the for-loop

Comment: You have used async keyword but there isn't any await keyword to make the code block await.

Comment: `The issue here is javascript is asynchronous as we all know.` Absolutely not. Afaik only setTimeout/setInterval, some to most events and *(still not too long ago)* iterators and promises are the only things where JS can interrupt the execution of code and become async, everything else executes synchronous.

Comment: how are `setErrorVinsArr` and `setValidatedVins` implemented? Are these react state-hooks? And where do `missingVinsArr` and `validatedVins` come from? We need more context about this code.

Comment: @Thomas yes there react state hooks basically these two arrays are two show valid and invalid list numbers on the page.

Comment: I can't give you an answer without **all relevant** code. That means everything that creates ot changes *any* of the variables in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(cb) {

    for (let x = 0; x < vinsToAnalyze.length; x++) {
      if (vinsToAnalyze[x].length > 10) {
        setErrorVinsArr([...errorVinsArr, vinsToAnalyze[x]]);
      } else {
        setValidatedVins([...validatedVins, vinsToAnalyze[x]]);
      }

   ## return callback when everything is done.
   ## Follow the pattern of shouting only after barking is done below 
   ## if `setErrorVinsArr` is supposed to take more time also.
   return cb();
 })(findMissing)
    
 function findMissing () {
    
    if (missingVinsArr.length <= validatedVins.length) {
         console.log('valid');
       } else {
         console.log('invalid');
       }
  }
```

You can have code performing synchronously this way. For example

```
function shout() {
    console.log('SHOUT')
}
```

You want to run shout but only after some function finish barking first.
So you would pass `shout` to barking as a reference it would be called as a call back when barking is finished.

```
(function(cb) { 
  console.log('barking');
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log('barking finished');
    cb() 
  }, 2000);
  console.log('still barking would finish after 2000');
})(shout)
```

You can run this example in console to understand better how it works.

Comment: Your code will never reach index `x === 1`. It will always break the loop after index `0`. And it will never call `cb` if the array is empty. And when you have fixed these things, you are back at the start; code that OP wrote.

Comment: You are right Thomas, callback should be returned only after all the work is done with for loop. I am not sure what's done in `setErrorVinsArr` but if that is causing delay than that should be sorted just like barking example. Thanks for helping me be aware of this concern.